# Audible books on iTunes

Tags: itunes, audiobook

I'm running sierra os and want to listen to my audible audiobooks on itunes. The audible website says that I don't need any additional software for Mac:

> Mac users using iTunes do not need to download any additional
>   software. Audible files will download directly into iTunes.

When I go to an audiobook section of my itunes I can't see anything. How do I import the audiobooks? I've downloaded them to the computer.

Comment: I'm assuming you've authorized your Audible account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it assumes that files will automatically get imported into iTunes. When I tested just now, the file downloads, but I certainly have to take action beyond that to get it into iTunes.

To import the files into iTunes, go to File > Add to Library (<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>), then browse to the folder where you downloaded the Audible file. Select the file(s) and click Open. They will be imported into iTunes and at that point you will find them in the Audiobooks section.